# How to send file with cURL exec PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this application where from a web page the user uploads a file, what i need to do is that the application sends this file to another API.

**Now i don't care what happens or what response i get after doing the cURL request** because it takes too long to process. i only notify the user that his/her file was uploaded correctly.

my code:

```
 curl_setopt_array(
                $ch,
                [
                    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_URL            => $this->endpoint,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $this->payload,
                ]
            );
            curl_exec($ch);
```

`$this->endpoint` contains the url and  `$this->payload` the file received.
From the API i sent that file i get the message that no file was sent or the file is in a incorrect format.
My guess is that i'm not sending the file correctly when executing the command. How to i can send that file?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/fck2ta/how-to-send-files-via-curl-in-php
Dont use exec please

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев I already read that, the file itself it's not on the server but received from another web request

Comment: Why don't you use the built-in `curl` functions of PHP? You can't use `curl_getinfo()` with `exec()`.

Comment: Content-Type: application/json ?
file bypass with "Content-Type: octet/stream" its first
Second? try save file and after that send it.
Next step send from memory be stream php-functions,
AND DO NOT exec() ))))

Comment: You can't do a file upload with `application/json` content-type. File uploads are done using `multipart/form-data` content-type.

Comment: Where is the file that you're trying to send? How is it related to `$this->payload`? Is that the filename or the file contents?

Comment: Your explanation of why you're doing it this way doesn't make sense. You're not running the command in the background, so `exec()` waits for the response.

Comment: use that! 
https://gist.github.com/iansltx/a6ed41d19852adf2e496

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев The method in your first link is obsolete. `@filename` is deprecated, you're supposed to use `curlFile` now.

Comment: DO NOT USE exec(); 
Just do it with hope )

Comment: thats what you want, just only understand! )))
https://gist.github.com/iansltx/a6ed41d19852adf2e496

Comment: "Now as why i'm implementing this way instead of using a library, is that i don't care what happens or what response i get after doing the cURL request because it takes too long to process. i only notify the user that his/her file was uploaded correctly." You can't know the file uploaded correctly until the request completes. This makes no sense; just use a library like Guzzle.

Comment: @НиколайЛубышев actually exec() would be ok if he would properly escape his arguments (with escapeshellarg()) - but he isn't doing that, so his code is vulnerable to shell injection via $this->payload :) (assuming a hacker can control $this->payload, and i'm guessing the answer is YES) - safe code would be ```$cmd.= " -d " . escapeshellarg(json_encode($this->payload)) . "```

Comment: if $payload is ```$payload=array('\'; echo shell injection! ;');``` then the command becomes ```-d '["'; echo shell injection! ; "]```- that code looks very vulnerable.

Comment: Sorry, but ... If the process takes a lot of time, then it is better to transfer it into  background script. It is just necessary to save somewhere information about this, for example, in the database. Just a comment)
Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `curl` functions.

```
$ch = curl_init($this->endpoint);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($this->payload),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json"
    ]
]);

if (curl_exec($ch)) {
    return [
        'code' => 200,
        'success' => True,
        'message' => curl_getinfo($cmd),
    ];
} else {
    return [
        'code' => curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE),
        'success' => false,
        'message' => "Curl failed"
    ];
}
```

Comment: that will wait until the entire upload is complete before returning. this guy probably needs [fastcgi_finish_request()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)